# Download is disallowed. The frame initiating or instantiating the download is sandboxed, but the flag ‘allow-downloads’ is not set. In LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, community, iframe, blob.topdf

> Download is disallowed. The frame initiating or instantiating the download is sandboxed, but the flag ‘allow-downloads’ is not set. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280 for more details.

I am trying to pass a blob content from Apex code to Js file in promise, I am using third party libraries like download.js and pdf-lib.js, using both I get the same error. I have read many articles in internet and got to know that Chrome and Edge has blocked downloading the files from iframes(was able to download in firefox) and says to keep sandbox='allow-downloads' but iam not sure where to keep that piece of code.

code

```
btnclickhandler(event){
    getBlob()
        .then(response => {
            var strFile = "data:application/pdf;base64,"+response;
            window.download(strFile, "sample.pdf", "application/pdf");
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error: ' + error.body.message);
        });
}
```

Comment: So the error is talking about iframe specifically.

How are you loading your component?

Answer (score 0):

Locker only supports opening `http:`, `https:`, `mailto:` schemes and relative urls. To achieve what you're trying to do, you need to slightly refactor your solution to generate a download link that users can click.

Users click a "Generate Download Link" button that gets the PDF content in Base64 format using Apex, and then generates a unique Blob URL for that content using `URL.createObjectURL` method. That Blob URL can then be shown to the users using an `<a>` tag containing the `download` attribute. Once a user clicks this, the content will be downloaded.

```html
<template>
    
    <template if:true={downloadUrl}>
        <a href={downloadUrl} download="filename.pdf">Download Now</a>
    </template>
    
    <template if:false={downloadUrl}>
        <lightning-button label="Generate Download Link" onclick={download}></lightning-button>
    </template>
    
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getPDFData from '@salesforce/apex/DownloadController.getPDFData';

export default class DownloadComponent extends LightningElement {

    downloadUrl;

    download(){
        getPDFData()
            .then(result => {
                const blob = this.b64toBlob(result, 'application/pdf');
                this.downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // TODO Error handling
            });
    }

    b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512){
        const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        const byteArrays = [];
      
        for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
          const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
      
          const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
          for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
          }
      
          const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
          byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }
      
        const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
        return blob;
      }
}
```

Comment: @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/2792205 for b64toBlob source...